# Finding all 11.04 compatible printers?

Tags: 11.04, printing

[OpenPrinting.org](http://www.openprinting.org/) is a great resource and service. But using it can be cumbersome. It's great for checking the compatibility of certain printers, but doing the reverse is tedious.

Is there a way to list all printers that come up compatible with a certain OS (like Ubuntu 11.04 for example)? Or is there a different site that might offer this kind of feature?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list for cups: http://www.cups.org/ppd.php which says '1234 printers found', listing always 20 per page. This would be 62 pages to download, easily doable with wget or a short shellscript and wget.

Parsing the html, and extracting the information should be an easy etude.

Another way is to inspect the names in the ppd-directory, where the drivers are:

```
 find /usr/share/ppd -name "*.ppd*" -type f | wc -l
```

but this only reveals 618 printers, nearly exactly the half of above number - maybe many of them serve different but similar models.

This for the list of drivers:

```
 find /usr/share/ppd -name "*.ppd*" -type f
```

Comment: All of the dates from the first 420 of the 1234 found are from Jan 18, 2005 or Aug 17, 2008. These couldn't have been tested for 11.04. Its a good start, though.

Comment: Why couldn't they have been tested, if they're older than the Distribution-version, they're running on? If they were younger, I would understand your concerns a bit more. But since they work, afaik, in userspace (it's `cupsd` running, loading `ppds`, not `.ko`-files), there isn't much to test on a new kernel, is it?

Comment: Because the Canon MF4350b worked in 10.10 and no longer does with 11.04.

Comment: Ok, I understand, that it doesn't work anymore. But how do you know it wasn't tested from the date/time? I can imagine that it wasn't tested, but what has the date to do with it? Are you talking about access time?

Comment: what do the dates signify if not when the drivers were tested?

Comment: The date of the driver doesn't change, when it is tested. How shall the date indicate, when it was tested? You can only argue, that a driver from 2011 could not have been tested 2009 - but maybe there was a change later, which didn't changed the way the driver works?